# Why does Cloudformation stack changeset include delete operations to delete SAM pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-sam

I've created an AWS SAM Hello World application, and have used the `sam pipeline init --bootstrap` command to create a pipeline for deployment. I've made minor modifications to the application including adding dynamoDB and changing the lambda function and name, but that shouldn't be causing this issue.

I'm seeing the following in the CodeBuild build logs

```
CloudFormation stack changeset

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Operation                LogicalResourceId        ResourceType             Replacement            

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

+ Add                    GatesDynamoDBTable       AWS::DynamoDB::Table     N/A                    

+ Add                    ServerlessRestApiDeplo   AWS::ApiGateway::Deplo   N/A                    
                         ymentd56c46fb52          yment                                           

+ Add                    ServerlessRestApiProdS   AWS::ApiGateway::Stage   N/A                    
                         tage                                                                     

+ Add                    ServerlessRestApi        AWS::ApiGateway::RestA   N/A                    
                                                  pi                                              

+ Add                    getGatesLambdaFunction   AWS::Lambda::Permissio   N/A                    
                         HelloWorldPermissionPr   n                                              
                         od                                                                       

+ Add                    getGatesLambdaFunction   AWS::IAM::Role           N/A                    
                         Role                                                                     

+ Add                    getGatesLambdaFunction   AWS::Lambda::Function    N/A                    

- Delete                 CodeBuildProjectBuildA   AWS::CodeBuild::Projec   N/A                    
                         ndPackage                t                                               

- Delete                 CodeBuildProjectDeploy   AWS::CodeBuild::Projec   N/A                    
                                                  t                                              

- Delete                 CodeBuildServiceRole     AWS::IAM::Role           N/A                    


- Delete                 CodePipelineExecutionR   AWS::IAM::Role           N/A                    
                         ole                                                                      

- Delete                 CodeStarConnection       AWS::CodeStarConnectio   N/A                    
                                                  ns::Connection                                  

- Delete                 PipelineArtifactsBucke   AWS::S3::BucketPolicy    N/A                    
                         tPolicy                                                                  

- Delete                 PipelineArtifactsBucke   AWS::S3::Bucket          N/A                    
                         t                                                                        

- Delete                 PipelineArtifactsLoggi   AWS::S3::BucketPolicy    N/A                    
                         ngBucketPolicy                                                           

- Delete                 PipelineArtifactsLoggi   AWS::S3::Bucket          N/A                    
                         ngBucket                                                                 

- Delete                 PipelineStackCloudForm   AWS::IAM::Role           N/A                    
                         ationExecutionRole                                                       

- Delete                 Pipeline                 AWS::CodePipeline::Pip   N/A                    
                                                  eline                                           

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have 2 yaml files in my project folder.

`template.yaml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Hello-World app

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  getGatesLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-getGatesLambdaFunction
      CodeUri: lambda_code/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
      Policies:
      # Give the Lambda service access to poll your DynamoDB Stream
      - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
  GatesDynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties: 
      TableName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Gates
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - AttributeName: gateId
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema: 
        - AttributeName: gateId
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  getGatesLambdaFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt getGatesLambdaFunction.Arn
  getGatesLambdaFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt getGatesLambdaFunctionRole.Arn
```

and `codepipeline.yaml`, which was generated by the `sam pipeline init --bootstrap` command.

My question is- why are these delete operations to delete the pipeline included in the deployment stage of the pipeline?

Neither `template.yaml` nor `codepipeline.yaml` contain these types of operations and I don't understand why the pipeline would try to delete itself while executing the deployment of the actual application. Could this be an issue because there is one stack that contains both the pipeline and the application? So that when the application is being deployed, it notices all these other things (the pipeline) that aren't included in the template it's deploying, so thinks they should be deleted? But if that's the case, the sam pipeline defaults are badly misconfigured...

Answer (score 0):

I also spent a lot of time to figure out how to solve this issue.

The name of the stack, that you inform during pipeline bootstrap, must be different than the stack name used by "sam deploy" command.

For example:

During pipeline bootstrap

```
What is the sam application stack name for stage 1? [sam-app]: <<stage1-sam-application-name-stack>>

What is the sam application stack name for stage 2? [sam-app]: <<stage2-sam-application-name-stack>>
```

After the pipeline bootstrap finishes

The sam deploy command

```
sam deploy -t codepipeline.yaml --stack-name <<deploy-sam-application-name-stack>> --capabilities=CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Remember that you can specify the stack name in the "samconfig.toml"

Hope this helps